# How to have fixed and scroll columns in the same table QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a table with some fixed columns and the others that can scrool (for example with a scrollBar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can be a solution, but [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html) you can find a working example of a table with a frozen first column, implemented using QWidget.
I think that it should be possible to implement it in Qml too to fit your needs.
Have a look ;)